# different ways for 'this' keyword in scala gives overloaded constructor error

Tags: scala, this, scala-collections

I have been trying to see usage of 'this' keyword in scala. I tried below program:

```
 class Person(name:String, age:Int){
  var id:Int=10
  def this(name:String, age:Int, i:Int){
      this(name, age)
      this.id = i }
  def show(): Unit = {
    println(this.name+" , "+this.age+" , "+id)}}
 object thisKeyword extends App{
  val t = new Person("Tom",21)
  t.show()}
```

Now what I understood was that the code will call this constructor and print Tom,21,10 as output which is on expected lines even if I'm passing only name and age. But when I remove the parameter from class Person like below and run it:

```
class Person{
```

It gives me error at below line:

```
val t = new Person("Tom",21)
```

> cannot overload constructor 'Person'

I don't understand why it says so? Why it is not using 'this' constructor definition that I have defined and should call that definition, along with default value of id. Also at below line:

```
this(name, age)
```

It gives error as

> Too many arguments for constructor 'Person'

Comment: If you remove your primary constructor, which takes a `String` and an `Int`, how do you expect to be able to call `this(name, age)` inside your secondary constructor? There no longer exists a constructor with that signature. The same goes for the `new Person("Tom", 21)` call outside. There is only 1 constructor in your class now - the one with 3 parameters, and you can't call it with 2 parameters. The compiler doesn't generate a constructor for you (except for no-args constructors if you don't define any constructors yourself, but that doesn't apply here)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got your point that since primary constructor is removed so `this(name,age)` will not work inside secondary constructor. But then how can I call the 'this' constructor with three parameters? As my understanding was when I don't take any class parameters like `class Person{` and call using `new Person("Tom",21)` it will refer to the this constructor and use default value for id.

Comment: To use the default value of id, you'll have to declare your secondary constructor as `def this(name:String, age:Int, i:Int = 10)`. It doesn't automatically take what you've set the field `id` to

Comment: So, I tweaked my code a bit and defined class variables name and age with default values . And then used this in my secondary constructor `this()
    this.name = name
    this.age = age`. It gives expected output and then I further tweaked it to `def this(name:String, age:Int)` and when I call this constructor as `new Person("Tim",22)` it get default 'id' value. My question is if I have to define and provide default values for each and every variable then what is the point of 'this' constructor?

Comment: That's not what secondary constructors are for. Most of the time, you don't need default values anyways. And secondary constructors are very useful if you want to have more than one way to create an object. Say you have a class that helps you write to a file. The primary constructor requires a `FileWriter` object, but you start to find it annoying when you have to first create a `FileWriter` object before creating an object of the aforementioned class, so you create a secondary constructor that takes in a `File` object and calls the primary constructor with a new FileWriter